# 'the series is' or 'the series are'? plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In mathematics, we have series, like

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...

Should I say 'the series is convergent' or 'the series are convergent'?

Comment: You might want to check this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23268/is-series-plural-or-singular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word 'series' is both a singular and plural form.  When it has the singular sense of 'one set', it takes a singular verb. When it has the plural sense of two or more sets, it takes a plural verb. For examples:

A series of lectures is scheduled.

Two series of lectures are scheduled: one for experts and one for laypeople. (The Free Dictionary).

1,2,3,4,5,....

Here we are talking about a set of numbers, so the right sentence is:

The series is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

> 1,2,3,4,5....

One series:
The series is _____

> 2,4,6,8,10...
>
> 1,4,9,16,25....

Two or more series:
The series are _____